# When to use associated type with constraint in Swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

```
    protocol Item {
      init(name: String)
    }

   //case1
    protocol SomeProtocol {
        associatedtype ItemType: Item
        var items: [ItemType] { get set }
    }

    //case2
    protocol SomeProtocol {
          var items: [Item] { get set }
    }
```

What is the difference in case 1 and case 2. As per my understanding, case 1 says, items is an array of any type that implements Item protocol and case 2 is kind of saying the same thing as protocols themselves can't be initiated.So items in case is again an array of objects that implements Item protocol.

Comment: Your two cases are unrelated. What is the point of comparing them? Unclear what the question is. Perhaps you do not understand what case 1 says? “But if we define the type itself in the protocol with associatedType” That is not what case 1 does.

Comment: Also please show the declaration of Item. What is it?

Comment: Item is a protocol. I got confused and was thinking that type of ItemType is declared as Item in case 1, but I get it now that ItemType could be any type that implements Item protocol.

Comment: Correct. If you now understand, please delete the question.

Comment: Modified question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, case 1 says, items is an array of any type that implements Item protocol and case 2 is kind of saying the same thing as protocols themselves can't be initiated.So items in case is again an array of objects that implements Item protocol.

Let's give your protocols better names to demonstrate how the two cases are different. Let's rename `SomeProtocol` to `ItemStorage`. Also, let's say there are two classes that conform to `Item`, `FooItem` and `BarItem`.

Now, I want to create two classes that implement `ItemStorage` called `FooItemStorage` and `BarItemStorage`. I want them to only be able to store their respective type of `Item`. If this were case 1, I could do this very easily:

```
class FooItemStorage: ItemStorage {
    typealias ItemType = FooItem
    var items: [FooItem] = []

    ...
}

class BarItemStorage: ItemStorage {
    typealias ItemType = BarItem
    var items: [BarItem] = []

    ...
}
```

However, in case 2, the arrays must be of type `[Item]`, so the above code won't compile. I have to do something like this:

```
class FooItemStorage: ItemStorage {
    typealias ItemType = FooItem
    var items: [Item] {
        get { return myItems }
        set {
            myItems = newValue as? [FooItem] ?? myItems
        }
    }
    var myItems: [FooItem] = []
    ...
}
```

I have to declare an extra property called `myItems` that has my desired type of `[FooItem]`, and delegate the getter and setter of `items` to `myItems`. Also, from the perspective of the client code, it looks as if `FooItemStorage` can now store any kinds of item.

Note this is not to say that protocols with associated types are always better. Protocols with associated types can't be used as the type of a variable. So if you don't need something like `FooItemStorage` and `BarItemStorage` where the conforming classes need different types, and you want to use the protocol as the type of a variable, you should not use associated types.